# Are tensors constructed such that one forms "act" on some complex vector field?

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, tensors, curvature

I am a physics student, trying to learn differential geometry. I have some confusion understanding the motivation in constructing tensors (or tensor fields). On a differentiable manifold $\mathcal{M}$ consider a vector field $X$. At any point $p\in \mathcal{M}$, we have the tangent space $T_p\left(\mathcal{M}\right)$ where we define the space of one-forms as linear maps  $\omega_p : T_p\left(\mathcal{M}\right) \rightarrow {\rm I\!R}$. This suggests that if I want to construct higher rank tensors, then I always need to construct some vector field which is acted on by a one form, so as to finally give a number - since tensors are defined as multilinear maps with ${\rm I\!R}$ as the range. As an example, consider the definition of the curvature tensor $R$ with vector fields $X,Y,Z$ and a one form (field) $\omega$ :

$$R\left(\omega, X,Y,Z\right) = \omega\left(\nabla_X\nabla_YZ - \nabla_Y\nabla_XZ - \nabla_{\left[X,Y\right]}Z\right)$$

Is this supposed to be interpreted as $\omega$ 'acting on' some vector field, such that we get a number? I am not convinced of this for two reasons:

1. In this case, the 'some vector field' would have to be $\left(\nabla_X\nabla_YZ - \nabla_Y\nabla_XZ - \nabla_{\left[X,Y\right]}Z\right)$ and I am not sure if this object is a vector field at all.
2. I know that there exist tensors that do not even act on vectors, such as the energy momentum tensor in physics, which is a map $T_p: T_p^*\left(\mathcal{M}\right) \otimes T_p^*\left(\mathcal{M}\right) \rightarrow \rm I\!R$. In this case I would have to choose a specific one form, if my interpretation of the tensor is as an object that constructs a vector field for a one form to act on, and ultimately take me to $\rm I\!R$.

Hence, do I just understand tensors to be operators that act on whatever objects they take as input? Or do we construct tensors based on how we define a one form - tensors as operations to construct a vector field which is then acted on by a one form, to ultimately give a number.

Comment: I would suggest you first read [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/664740/203278) of mind at PhySE. Tensors can be defined as certain multilinear maps. Now, regarding the Riemann tensor, in my answer there, I defined $R(X,Y)Z$ and said "after dualizing appropriately... (1,3) tensor field"; this corresponds to what you've written here. Now, regarding your Q1, why do you think that object is not a vector field? If $X,Y$ are vector fields, then by definition $\nabla_XY$ is a vector field. So, $\nabla_X(\nabla_YZ)$ is also a vector field, likewise for the other two terms.

Comment: The question of 'what' the tensors eat depends on the type of the tensor $(r,s)$. The Riemann curvature tensor field as you've described it here is of type $(1,3)$. By double-duality, vector fields can be thought of as $(1,0)$ tensor fields. Covector fields/one-forms are $(0,1)$ tensor fields. Energy-momentum tensor fields are either as $(0,2)$ tensor fields or $(2,0)$ or $(1,1)$ (we don't make a definite specification here because in physics, using the Lorentzian metric of spacetime one can 'convert' between these types).

Comment: I think I was confused about $\nabla_X Y$ because if in some basis $X = X^a \partial_a, Y = Y^b \partial_b$, then the components of the covariant derivative, $\nabla_aY^b$ should transform like a $(1,1)$ tensor right?

Comment: If $T$ is an $(r,s)$ tensor field, then $\nabla T$ is an $(r,s+1)$ tensor field. But once you fill the lower slot with a vector field $X$, then $\nabla_XT$ is an $(r,s+1-1)=(r,s)$ tensor field. In particular, if $Y$ is a vector field (equivalently a $(1,0)$ tensor field) then $\nabla Y$ is a $(1,1)$ tensor field; but filling in the lower slot we get a $(1,0)$ tensor field $\nabla_XY$ (i.e a vector field).

Comment: Essentially what I am asking is that if I consider the Riemann tensor defined in the way above, if I do not have to consider it as $\omega$ acting on the vector field constructed out of $X,Y,Z$ and the Levi-Civita connection, then can I equivalently write $R\left(\omega, X,Y,Z\right) = \left(\nabla_X\nabla_YZ - \nabla_Y\nabla_XZ - \nabla_{\left[X,Y\right]}Z\right)\omega$?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you cant. An element of a vector space $V$ does not directly act on an element of $V^*$. However, an element of $V^{**}$ (which is canonically isomorphic to $V$; this is known as double duality) can act on an element of $V^*$. So, to be fully precise, if you let $\iota$ be the isomorphism from the space of vector fields to their double dual, you can write $R(\omega,X,Y,Z)=[\iota(\text{nabla stuff})](\omega)$, but then by definition this is just $\omega(\text{nabla stuff})$. So, unless you're fully comfortable with this double duality, I suggest you not abbreviate language.

Comment: So that means that as long as I am not looking at double duality, tensors are constructed so as to make one forms act on vectors in order to produce a scalar. Then, how do we construct/understand $(n,0)$ or $(0,n)$ tensor fields, since I will not have both one forms and tensors as inputs?

Comment: A $(0,n)$ tensor eats $n$ vectors and produces a number. You're already very familiar with such tensors, even if you were never explicitly made aware of this. FOr example, the inner/dot product is a $(0,2)$ tensor (we take two vectors $v,w$ and output a number $\langle v,w\rangle$; this is so prevalant in all of physics; entry level all the way up to GR and quantum mechanics). Next, the determinant (i.e very closely related to volumes) of an $n\times n$ matrix can be thought of as $\det$ acting on the $n$ columns of the matrix. This is a $(0,n)$ tensor on $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Moment of inertia is another classic example of a $(0,2)$ (or $(2,0)$ or $(1,1)$ depending who you talk to) tensor. (In electrodynamics, the electromagnetic potential $A$ is a $1$-form; its exterior derivative $F=dA$ is a 2-form, i.e an antisymmetric $(0,2)$ tensor field (this is the $F_{\mu\nu}$ object you may be seen before))

Comment: Yeah I am aware of these examples. My issue is not so much with with what they mean, but more of what is happening - i.e how do I understand what the objects that are being eaten, are doing. Do I always have to think of a tensor as some manipulation of the input objects arranged so as to get one form $\times$ vector? If so, how is this done when the input doesn't have either one forms, or vectors?

Comment: If the input doesn't have 1-forms or vectors, then you don't call that object a tensor. By definition a tensor (on a vector space $V$) eats some number of vectors (elements of $V$) and some number of covectors (elements of $V^*$) and **according to some specific rule**, outputs (multilinearly) a number in $\Bbb{R}$ (or $\Bbb{C}$, or a field $\Bbb{F}$ if you're doing abstract algebra). If you want to talk about concrete examples, then you have to give specific definitions for this 'rule'. You don't always need a vector-1form pair to make a scalar.

Comment: Your first and last sentence seem very confusing to me. Is the metric a tensor then, because the way I understand it, it only takes in 2 vectors (and no one forms) and still gives a number. At least in a coordinate basis, $g\left(X,Y\right) = g_{\mu \nu}X^\mu Y^\nu$ which is the rule that defines the metric tensor. So for objects that do not take in one forms as input, we have a way to construct a scalar without having a vector one form pair (which you say is not needed always). But is this not a tensor because it doesn't take one forms as inputs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136153/discussion-between-peek-a-boo-and-newtothis).